# How can I use the tab key to choose an item on Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the component [MenuItem](https://material-ui.com/es/api/menu-item/) (material-UI) and I'm trying to choose an item when user press the 'tab' key, something like that:

```
{Object.keys(Countries).map(key => (
   <MenuItem key={key} value={Countries[key]} onKeyDown={(ev) => {                  
      if(ev.key === 'Tab') {
       //How can I choose the selected item with tab key?
      }
     }}>
     {Countries[key]}
    </MenuItem>
))}
```

Comment: You need to show more of the code. Are you using this within a `Select` or a `Menu`?

Comment: I'm using the `TextField` component, passing the param `select`.

Comment: Do you want to select the menu item, or focus it and navigate by Tab presses?

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just use the onKeyDown prop on the menu item.. and since you're already doing a .map you have access to the items id or whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need the menu item to have access to the change-handler for the Select. When a <kbd>Tab</kbd> occurs, it should send the menu item's `value` to the change-handler in a similar manner as occurs on click -- via `event.target.value`.

Below is a working example:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    width: 200
  },
  dense: {
    marginTop: 19
  },
  menu: {
    width: 200
  }
}));

const currencies = [
  {
    value: "USD",
    label: "$"
  },
  {
    value: "EUR",
    label: "€"
  },
  {
    value: "BTC",
    label: "฿"
  },
  {
    value: "JPY",
    label: "¥"
  }
];
const SelectOnTabMenuItem = React.forwardRef(
  ({ "data-value": valueForEvent, value, onChange, ...other }, ref) => {
    const handleKeyDown = event => {
      if (event.key === "Tab") {
        event.persist();
        // Getting the value from the "data-value" prop is necessary
        // due to the manner in which Material-UI clones the MenuItem during
        // display of the Select: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.5.1/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L226
        event.target = { value: valueForEvent };
        onChange(event);
      }
    };
    return (
      <MenuItem ref={ref} value={value} onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} {...other} />
    );
  }
);

export default function TextFields() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    currency: currencies[0]
  });

  const handleChange = name => event => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
  };
  const currencyHandleChange = handleChange("currency");
  return (
    <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField
        id="standard-select-currency"
        select
        label="Select"
        className={classes.textField}
        value={values.currency}
        onChange={currencyHandleChange}
        SelectProps={{
          MenuProps: {
            className: classes.menu
          },
          renderValue: option => option.label
        }}
        helperText="Please select your currency"
        margin="normal"
      >
        {currencies.map(option => (
          <SelectOnTabMenuItem
            onChange={currencyHandleChange}
            key={option.value}
            value={option}
          >
            {option.label} ({option.value})
          </SelectOnTabMenuItem>
        ))}
      </TextField>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Select item on Tab]